# Is there a way to classify the finite fields where $x^2+1$ has a root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

It is a well-known theorem in number theory that $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and $-1$ is not a square if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. Furthermore, $-1$ is easily seen to be a square in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ for any $n$.

If $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, I think $-1$ is still a square in any $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ for all $n$. Each $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ still contains $\mathbb{F}_p$ as its prime subfield, and there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_p$, hence $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ such that $\alpha^2+1=0$.

What happens in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ when $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$? My guess is that $-1$ is not a square,, since maybe there is a way to knock a solution to $x^2+1=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ back down to a solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$ to reach a contradiction, but I am unsure.

Comment: Just use that the multiplicative groups are always cyclic. Then when is there a non-trivial $4$th root of unity?

Comment: Just take the splitting field of $X^2+1$ over $F_p$ where $p\equiv 3\;[4]$. This is $F_{p^2}$. $F_{p^n}$ will contain a root of $-1$ iff it is an extension of $F_{p^2}$, iff $n$ is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p=2$ then $x=1$ is the unique solution. Else $x^2+1=0\Leftrightarrow x^2=-1\Leftrightarrow x^4=1$ and $x^2\ne1$.

The cyclic group $\Bbb F_{p^n}^\times$ has an element of order $4$ if and only if $4$ divides its order, $\,p^n-1$.

It suffices to consider $p\equiv3~(4)$. Determine $p^n$ mod $4$ based on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: Very helpful thank you